# istanbul with mocha not generating coverage report when a testcase takes more time

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, istanbul

I am testing my js file using `mocha`. Some of the testcases takes time in resolving response so i used timeout with it. Complete command looks like

> istanbul cover _mocha test/sol-verifier.js -- --timeout 300000

Problem is that while going for the coverage like this, I am not getting coverage report  created, it only runs testcases successfully and stops (not terminates). How can i solve this?

My code is in node.js and it doesn't create any server.

Also when i remove `--timeout` flag and comment out the test cases that take more time. It works fine and generates the coverage report.

As per my findings, problem is not in the `--timeout` flag, report is not generated when there is a testcase taking longer than usual to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `done` argument to your test suite functions and invoke `done()` at the end of each of your test functions:

```
it('test expectation', function(done) {
    // test asynchronous code
    // call done() to terminate test and proceed to the next test
    done();
}
```

Alternatively, try running your tests with the `--exit` flag on `mocha`:

`istanbul cover _mocha --exit test/sol-verifier.js -- --timeout 300000`

According to the [docs](https://boneskull.com/mocha-v4-nears-release/#mochawontforceexit):

> To avoid false positives and encourage better testing practices, Mocha will no longer [automatically kill itself](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2879) via process.exit() when it thinks it should be done running.
>
> If the mocha process is still alive after your tests seem "done", then your tests have scheduled something to happen (asynchronously) and haven't cleaned up after themselves properly. Did you leave a socket open?
>
> Supply the --exit flag to use pre-v4 behavior.